# Mypy complains correct protocol implementation as invalid return type

Tags: python, mypy, static-analysis

attached is a minimal implementation to which I cannot figure out the error message from mypy and would like to know if any of you have an idea or experience on how I can convince mypy that the return value `dict[str, DataProtocol]` is compatible with my own `dict[str, MyData]`.

So far I didn't find anything in the documentation of mypy and also here.
Would appreciate more background on how mypy does such evaluation.

```
python==3.10.6
mypy==1.3.0
```

```python
from typing import Protocol
from dataclasses import dataclass

# ======= Protocol ========
class DataProtocol(Protocol):
    name: str 

class ReadProtocol(Protocol):
    def read(self) -> dict[str, DataProtocol]:
        ...

# ==== Implementation =====
@dataclass
class MyData:
    name: str = "default"

class MyReader:
    def read(self) -> dict[str, MyData]: 
        return {"test" : MyData()}

# ======= Test ============
mydata: DataProtocol = MyData() # -> OK
mydict: dict[str, DataProtocol] = {"test" : MyData()} # -> OK

reader: ReadProtocol = MyReader() # -> mypy error:
# Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "MyReader", variable has type "ReadProtocol")  [assignment]mypy(error)
# Following member(s) of "MyReader" have conflicts:mypy(note)
#     Expected:mypy(note)
#         def read(self) -> Dict[str, DataProtocol]mypy(note)
#     Got:mypy(note)
#         def read(self) -> Dict[str, MyData]mypy(note)
# class MyReader()
```

Considering the link `sytech` shared as possible answer.
So far, I cannot agree. Since this example is accepted by mypy.
Also here I change the signature of the function and return my own type. But not enclosed in a dictionary

```python
# ======= Protocol ========
class DataProtocol(Protocol):
    name: str 

class ReadProtocol(Protocol):
    def read(self) -> DataProtocol:
        ...

# ==== Implementation =====
@dataclass
class MyData:
    name: str = "default"

class MyReader:
    def read(self) -> MyData: 
        return MyData()

# ======= Test ============
reader: ReadProtocol = MyReader() # -> OK
```

Dumped a combination of both into the mypy playground.
Maybe it's an issue to file as bug.

https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=0d30ca22abd2ecea93013e04bedf335c

Comment: Thanks sytech, I added another use case without putting the MyData type in a dictionary which shows that mypy treats them differently.

Comment: Good point, I agree this seems like something different.

Comment: [Here is minimal example](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=1.3.0&python=3.11&gist=042237547ca2bf93dd41bb5b046c2792) without the need for additional classes. You will see the same results, if you use `list[float]`/`list[int]` as the return types by the way, but not with `tuple`s. So my guess is it has to do with the rejection of covariant subtyping with mutable objects, similar to [this](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#covariant-subtyping-of-mutable-protocol-members-is-rejected). But I don't have enough time right now to investigate further.

Comment: Daniil, this ist not the same. My Implementation assumes that the DataProtocol and MyData are valid concerning static type checking. In your example you override float with int which does not match.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg you're correct of course, `dict[str, int]` is not a subtype of `dict[str, float]` due to variance, so they cannot be return types of a class and subclass. Return types are covariant.

Comment: To OP: consider using a typevar to resolve the variance issue, like [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=1.3.0&python=3.11&gist=073c0093c0e0da45faf9272388a2917f) (gist mine). LMK if this works for you, I'll prepare an answer with further explanations. (and yes, the simplified MRE by Daniil reproduces exactly the same issues just with less code)

Comment: @Zap `int` is a subtype of `float` by convention. And [mypy conforms to this convention](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/duck_type_compatibility.html).

Comment: Yes, Daniil you are right and thank you for the conventions considered by mypy.
I'm more focused on the usage of Protocols. Having proper type hints and code completion for the user.

Comment: @SUTerliakov, thank you for this proposal. I need some time to understand this solution, but what I've already observed, mypy is happy when I apply this change. 
But the downside is, in vscode I do no longer have any code completion for this return type and the signatures return type is declared as `dict[str, Any]` . 
Using `typing.get_type_hints` I get `{'return': dict[str, ~_T]}` instead.

Comment: I don't use vscode and don't have it installed, so sorry, can't help with that issue (and I don't fully understand what exactly is wrong - if it shows available attributes, what else do you want from autocompletion?) Regarding `get_type_hints` - yes, this is a real drawback, since you replace an easily manageable annotation with a mid complex one (though you can read an upper bound of typevar at runtime)

Comment: This is the point. Vscode does not show the available attributes. From vscodes perspective the dicts value is handled as  of type Any. Which is for my use case the the bigger downside.

Comment: Pycharm seems to support this, according to this ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-25832/Autocompletion-for-TypeVar-doesnt-consider-its-upper-bounds

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not an answer, but a workaround I found.
In the user code, not in the protocol, I added `Any` as an optional type annotation for the value.

This way mypy does not trigger any complaints and the code completion in vscode still works.

I don't think this is the best solution, as I could imagine mypy is not able to detect an invalid attribute access on the value objects, since those could be anything.

```python
class MyReader:
    def read_one(self) -> MyData: # This is OK
        return MyData()
        
    def read_all(self) -> dict[str, MyData|Any]: # Workaround: Use `Any` to avoid mypy "incompatible types" error
        return {"test" : MyData()}
```

Comment: This effectively destroys all the typechecking, since you allow anything in dict values.

Comment: That's correct and not my preferred solution but better than a type: ignore comment or a declaration not compatible with the code  completion of vscode. Have not checked with another IDE yet.